# Auto complete values of the parameters powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am trying to find the way to create values for parameters that can be auto completed or show all available options with tab, like the value "allsigned" in the cmdlet

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy AllSigned
```

¿Any ideas about how this is called in programation or how can I achieve this ?

Comment: btw, seems that you aint on win10/powershell 5. have a look at   https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes its called [validateset](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx)

```
Param
      (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateSet("Low", "Average", "High")]
        [String[]]
        $Detail
      )
```

Comment: can validateset be set during execution ?

Answer (score 6):

advanced functions/cmdlets or just parameter validation, parameter sets, etc

snippet from the ISE:

```
function Verb-Noun
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Parameter Set 1', 
                  SupportsShouldProcess=$true, 
                  PositionalBinding=$false,
                  HelpUri = 'http://www.microsoft.com/',
                  ConfirmImpact='Medium')]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([String])]
    Param
    (
        # Param1 help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, 
                   ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false, 
                   Position=0,
                   ParameterSetName='Parameter Set 1')]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateCount(0,5)]
        [ValidateSet("sun", "moon", "earth")]
        [Alias("p1")] 
        $Param1,

        # Param2 help description
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Parameter Set 1')]
        [AllowNull()]
        [AllowEmptyCollection()]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [ValidateScript({$true})]
        [ValidateRange(0,5)]
        [int]
        $Param2,

        # Param3 help description
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Another Parameter Set')]
        [ValidatePattern("[a-z]*")]
        [ValidateLength(0,15)]
        [String]
        $Param3
    )

    Begin
    {
    }
    Process
    {
        if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess("Target", "Operation"))
        {
        }
    }
    End
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for all those examples and the recomendations about powershell 5 :)

Comment: `ValidatePattern` doesn't seem to help completion. I was going to filter file by extension.